# I need some help with the syntax of David Marker's introduction to Model Theory

Tags: logic, model-theory

I seem to have gotten the hang of most of his syntax in the early chapters, but I need help/translation with a few details

For

> ii) If $s$ is the variable, $v_{ij}$, then $s^M(\overline{a}) = a_{ij}$

What does '$j$-ary' stand for? Why does he use '$j$' instead of '$n$' in other examples, such as  (vii) of Definition 1.1.6 and a tuple ordered $1$ to $m$ rather than $1$ to $n$?

Do these have distinct meaning from $n$-ary's?

Comment: After the quotation, you ask what "$j$-ary" stands for, but "$j$-ary" doesn't occur in the quotation.

Comment: What would you say is the best interpretation of the quotation as a whole?

Comment: Without further context, it seems to me that there is a matrix of variables $v_{i,j}$, which are being interpreted as elements of (the universe of) a structure $M$ by means of a matrix $\overline a$ of elements of $M$. Variable $v_{i.j}$ gets interpreted as the $i,j$ entry $a_{i,j}$ of the matrix $\overline a$.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense.